# Starting up a project downloaded from Github

Tags: github, download, project

I am new to coding and am having trouble starting up a new project I am wanting to apply something to. Here is the repository I am working from: https://github.com/herrcui/RailView

I have the latest python and java programmes installed and have no idea where to start looking at these files:

[image: File path]

Comment: Hi - this problem is something you should ask the developers of the project, not stack overflow. There's a lot of different ways programs can be compiled/run, and unless the project is well documented or you can talk to the original developers, there isn't always a obvious way to do it. You may need to try trial and error based on the files and filetypes you can see in the project.